# How to replace appcache lifecycle event with ServiceWorker lifecycle

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I am trying to change appcache to serviceworker in my application for offline work. I have removed manifest tag from html page and created serviceworker.js as of lifecycle events. But, appcache events are being used like this below:

```
function framework(){
    this.appCache = window.applicationCache;
  //more other codes
}
  var fw = new framework();
```

Now, lifecycle events are checked like this:

```
if (fw.appCache) {
/* Checking for an update. Always the first event fired in the sequence.*/ fw.appCache.addEventListener('checking',    handleCacheEvent, false);
/* An update was found. The browser is fetching resources.*/               fw.appCache.addEventListener('downloading', handleCacheEvent, false);
/* Fired if the manifest file returns a 404 or 410.
   This results in the application cache being deleted. */                 fw.appCache.addEventListener('obsolete',    handleCacheEvent, false);
/* The manifest returns 404 or 410, the download failed,
   or the manifest changed while the download was in progress.*/           fw.appCache.addEventListener('error',       handleCacheError, false);
/* Fired for each resource listed in the manifest as it is being fetched.*/fw.appCache.addEventListener('progress',    handleProgressEvent, false);
/*Fired after the first cache of the manifest. */                          fw.appCache.addEventListener('cached',  function(event){handleCacheEvent(event);removeProcessing();$("#processingTextId").html("");}, false);
/* Fired after the first download of the manifest.*/                       fw.appCache.addEventListener('noupdate', function(event){handleCacheEvent(event);removeProcessing(); $("#processingTextId").html("");}, false);
/* Fired when the manifest resources have been newly redownloaded. */      fw.appCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {if (fw.appCache.status == fw.appCache.UPDATEREADY) {alert('Successful'); try{fw.appCache.swapCache();window.location.reload();} catch(err){}}}, false);
```

}

```
function handleCacheEvent(event) {$("#processingTextId").html(event.type);}
function handleProgressEvent(event) {$("#processingTextId").html("(" + event.loaded + " of "+ event.total +")");}
function handleCacheError(event) {$("#processingTextId").html("Cache failed to update!")
```

So, my question is how to replace this events with service worker events. My serviceworker is registered and caching the assets properly. Now, i am doing like this in index.html

**Registartion**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworker.js')
            .then(registration =>{
                console.log('registration successful:',registration.scope);
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log('registration failed:',err);
            });
    }


    </script>
```

I have created the seperate serviceworker.js.

How to replace those appcache events with serviceworker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't end up with any of those events automatically when using a service worker. Also, the model for when a service worker populates and updates a cache is much more "open ended" than with AppCache, so translating service worker caching into equivalent AppCache events is not always possible.

In general, though, here are two things that can help:

Read up on the [Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#scope_and_control). Some events that you might care about could be approximated by listening for equivalent changes to the service worker lifecycle. For instance, if you [precache some URLs during service worker installation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook#on-install-as-dependency), then a newly registered service worker leaving the `installing` state would be roughly equivalent to when an AppCache manifest finishes caching. Similarly, if you detect when there's an update to a previously registered service worker (and that update is due to a change in the list of URLs to precache), then that would roughly correspond to when an AppCache manifest is updated.

If your service worker uses "runtime" caching, where URLs are added to the cache inside of a `fetch` handler, that you could use the following technique to tell your client page(s) when new items have been cached, using [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate.

*Part of your service worker's JavaScript:*

```
const cacheAddAndNotify = async (cacheName, url) => {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  await cache.add(url);
  const clients = await self.clients.matchAll();
  for (const client of clients) {
    client.postMessage({cacheName, url});
  }
};

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Use cacheAddAndNotify() to add to your cache and notify all clients.
});
```

*Part of your web app's JavaScript:*

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    const {cacheName, url} = event.data;
    // cacheName and url represent the entry that was just cached.
  });
}
```

Again, the specifics of what you listen for and how you react to it are really going to depend on exactly what logic you have in your service worker. Don't expect there to be a 1:1 mapping between all events. Instead, use this migration as an opportunity to think about what cache-related changes you actually care about, and focus on listening for those (via service worker lifecycle events, or `postMessage()` communication).

Comment: Jeff, thanks for your response. I have followed your response. Now, i have one open question regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193797/how-to-cache-ajax-response-by-using-serviceworker    Can you give me any suggestion or notify the changes for this?